# How to add google datastore package to electron app

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore, electron, yarnpkg

My first electron app: it's an admin app intended to run only on my machine

I want to add the @google-cloud/datastore module to it, but electron won't start once I import the package.

I add the package using 'yarn add', then rebuild for electron using electron-rebuild as instructed here: https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules

The first error is:

```
Failed to compile
./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/channel.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'http2' in '<...>\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src'
```

So I try manually yarn add'ing http2, electron-rebuild, and 'yarn start', after which I get a few warnings:

```
./node_modules/http2/lib/protocol/index.js                                                                                                              
Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted                                            
./node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js                                                                                                               
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression                                                                                      
./node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/pre-binding.js                                                                                       
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression                                                                                      
./node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/versioning.js
```

The app then starts but shows a long list of errors.

```
Error: Cannot find module './../process/browser.js'
... intermediate errors, below is the module trying to import
Module../node_modules/merge2/index.mjs
```

I'm not sure if/what I'm doing wrong, or if google datastore is somehow not compatible with electron?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the latest Electron & google packages (and no other changes) seems to have resolved this issue